# Is there any sample code to integrate Facebook chat into our own iphone application?

Tags: objective-c

Is there any sample code to integrate Facebook chat into my own iphone application.

Anyone's help will be deeply appreciated,

Thanks to all,
Madan.

Comment: You can go throw the tutorial: [FaceBook Integration](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app)

Comment: Actually my need is to integrate Facebook chat into my application.

Comment: You should google about Facebook Chat API under iOS, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/, the API docs are not iOS specific but I think they are clear enough to extrapolate the implementation in Objective-C or anything else...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the cocoa framework xmppframework which has instructions on how to implement facebook chat [here](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/FacebookChatHowTo)

Failing that there is the Pidgin Facebook Chat plugin, which is written in C. You should be able to write a wrapper for the plugin to make using your own methods fairly easily. Also it seems to have been updated fairly recently (2 months ago), so should be in a working state.

Also read through the [Facebook chat docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/).